According to the official and latest result, Earth's mass is 5.972 x 10^24. How is this answer obtained and what is the formula?
The formula to get the answer of the earth's mass which is 5.972 x 10^24 kg.

Not that it changes the answer, but you should edit the question to add the units of the mass.

Does this not answer your question, Earth mass? You should also state the source of the number you used.
